# Outputting datetime date to dropdown list from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I have a webpage that populates a dropdown control using `SqlDataSource`.

I want to return date values from a table and output them into the dropdownbox, 
The code I have to do this, which works in the query builder is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (varchar(10), Appointmentdatetime, 103) 
FROM Visit AS date
```

However when I run this, the following error occurs

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When I modify the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Appointmentdatetime, 126) 
FROM Visit AS date
```

it behaves correctly.

I need the date to output to dd/MM/yyyy. Can anyone offer any help on the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try this way: CONVERT(VARCHAR,Appointmentdatetime,103)
There is a issue with time zones settings where the pattern dd/MM/yyyy for some time zones not works well.

Comment: I wouldn't convert DB side, I'd convert dates in your web app. E,g  `dateVal.ToString("pick a format")`. You'd probably want the display value as you've described but the value to be a more generic format. Also is `Appointmentdatetime` a DateTime data type in the DB?

Comment: @JonP Convert them on input, or on output? 
Yes, Appointmentdatetime is datetime data type

Comment: Both, as all form fields are string values. This is why you are better off just pulling dates as DateTime types from the DB. Use the .net inbuilt functinality to handle formatting/converstion/parsing. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this

`SELECT convert(varchar, cast(Appointmentdatetime as date), 103)  FROM Visit as date`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (Date, Appointmentdatetime, 103) as dates FROM Visit
```